# DataTable.Load returning 'Cannot convert string to int' when using parameters

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to execute a SQL statement that simply returns the value of a parameter.

In the below example, my command is `'Select txtName = ?'` and I add a single string parameter with a value of 'test':

```
OdbcCommand command = CreateCommand(query, controls);
command.Connection = _OdbcConnection;
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
ExtendedDataTable Results = new ExtendedDataTable();
Results.Load(reader);
return Results;
```

When this attempts to load the results into the Results table, I receive an error "Cannot convert 'test' to a int".

I have also confirmed from the DataTable.GetSchemaTable() command that it does think my value is of type int16, which it obviously is not.

If I run the below statement instead, it works perfectly fine, so I know my parameter is working

```
Select txtName = 'test' where ? = 'test'
```

If it helps, the OdbcCommand is connecting to a SQL Anywhere 11 database. Also, the ExtendedDataTable type is basically just a DataTable (nothing special that should impact types).

Comment: My eyes hurt. Before learning to convert string to int, start learning how to use parameters to avoid sql-injection first.

Comment: Can you share the complete value of `query` variable?